# 5th element from end of singly linked list without traversing the list

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I have written the below code for finding the 5th element from the end of a singly linked list.List should not be traversed more than once.Assumption is that list size cannot be known without traversing the list. Does my code satisfies the question? I have seen the same question solved using pointers so I am confused if my approach is wrong.

```
public class LinkedList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> inputListStr = new ArrayList<String>();
        java.util.LinkedList<String> outputList = new java.util.LinkedList<String>();
        System.out.println("Enter comma separated input");
        Scanner Scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        inputListStr = Arrays.asList(Scan1.next().split(","));
        outputList.addAll(inputListStr);
        nthElement(outputList);
        Scan1.close();
    }

    public static void nthElement(java.util.LinkedList<String> outputList) {

        int counter = 0;
        for (String list : outputList) {
            counter++;
        }

        System.out.println("5th element is " + outputList.get(counter - 5));

    }
}
```

Comment: You should ask your teacher, but I would say no, because `get` will probably traverse the list. HINT: while traversing, always keep a pointer to the 5 previous elements

Comment: I would also suggest not naming your class the same thing as the java.util.LinkedList class - it's confusing.

Answer (score 1):

`LinkedList` and `ArrayList` keep size as an `int` inside the instance. Therefore, checking the size does not count as traversing the list.

So, your problem can be solved using one line of code:

```
Object solution = list.get(list.size() - 5);
```

Of course you will need to add some checks, like if the size of the list is at least 5, but you get the idea ^^

Comment: Have added the checks..and I hope solving this problem without the use of pointers is fine.